# How to redirect URLs with changing a path, but maintaining a parameter on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have two URLs with single parameter and a combination of two. They should be redirected with 301, but redirects must affect only pathes, but maintain same parameters/parameter combinations):

1. `https://example.com/a?x=y` → `https://example.com/b/c?x=y`
2. `https://example.com/a?x=y&z=0` → `https://example.com/d?x=y&z=0`

I've tried to workout both cases with

```
location ~ ^/a/?(.*) {
^/b/c$1$is_args$args permanent;
}
```

and

```
location ~ ^/a/?(.*) {
^/d/$1$is_args$args permanent;
}
```

but it seems to be wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/a(/.*$|$)  # capture group $1 will not have any parameters/args!
{
    return 303 $scheme://$server_name/b/c$1$is_args$args;
}
```

and

```
location ~ ^/a(/.*$|$)  # in fact, location will never "see" parameters/args!
{
    return 303 $scheme://$server_name/d$1$is_args$args;
}
```

`$` at end of regex will you give trailing "uri path" (after `/a` and before questionmark `?`) in your capture group `$1`.

Untested.

---

OK, now I understand your question. LOL. Gimmi a sec.

---

I know `if` is evil. But I think I need it.

```
location ~ ^/a(/.*$|$)
{
    set $target_uri '/b/c';
    set $change_target_uri '';
    if ($arg_x)  # you can't have `and` in Nginx `if` condition!
    {
        set $change_target_uri "${change_target_uri}_x";
    }
    if ($arg_y)  # so use variable $change_target_uri as a workaround:
    {
        set $change_target_uri "${change_target_uri}_y";
    }
    if ($change_target_uri = '_x_y')
    {
        set $target_uri '/d';
    }
    return 303 $scheme://$server_name$target_uri$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Check with `curl -IL https://example.com/a/blah?x=y&z=0` and look for `303` and `Location:`.

Untested.

---

Another method comes to mind.

```
location ~ ^/a(?<blubbi>/.*$|$)
{
    if ($args ~* 'x=[^&]*(?:&[^z]|&$|$)')
    {
        return 303 $scheme://$server_name/b/c$blubbi?x=$arg_x;
    }
    if ($args ~* 'x=[^&]*&z=[^&]*')
    {
        return 303 $scheme://$server_name/d$blubbi?x=$arg_x&y=$arg_y;
    }
}
```

Use only when order of parameters is fixed.

Untested.

---

In general regarding Nginx and Regex:

- I like named variables (see `blubbi`). So no mixup with `$1` in different scopes (http, server, location, deeper location, if, ...).
- `[^a]+` will match all characters except of `a`.
- So `[^&]*` will make sure that you get the whole argument but not more.